# How to make a C# Discord Bot copy what the user says (like a !say command)

Tags: c#, bots, discord

So, before you think I'm a complete idiot, I am pretty new to C#, so my skills are in no way good.

Basically, I want to make a !say command for my Discord bot (example: user: !say bleh - bot: bleh)

I am so sorry for anyone that does help me, but appreciate it much.

```
private void RegisterSayCommand()
{
    commands.CreateCommand("say")
        .Do(async (e) =>
        {
           await e.Channel.SendMessage("")
        });
}
```

From this code on, I have no idea what to do, and I'd assume the working code would look nothing like that. Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to treat the message as a parametr. Something like this I can imagine:

```
command.CreateCommand("say").Parameter("message", ParameterType.Multiple).Do( async (e) = > 
{
  string message = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < e.Args.Length; i++) 
  {
    message += e.Args[i].ToString() + " ";
  }
  await e.Channel.SendMessage(message);
}
```